# Can I set up weeklong time limit using Parental Controls?

Tags: parental-controls

Is it possible to set up a system where daily time limits are in place, while having a weeklong, continuous total allowed time? For example, a total of 14 hours per week which can be budgeted, while maintaining a limit on when that allotted time can be used (7am - 10pm)? Even better if a limit on time used per day can be instituted, preventing, for example, binging movies for 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

No - Setting weekly limits (like only being able to use an apps for 14 hours each week) is not possible on iOS 15.4.1.

You can set daily limits for the number of hours the user can I specific apps, websites and app categories. These limits can differ based on day of the week.

You can limit the use of the device to only specific apps during certain hours.

All parental control settings are available in **Settings→Screen Time**.

For more information, you can read the Apple Support article [Use Screen Time on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982).